# Is camping on the roof legal?

Tags: austria

### TLDR

Although I am disabled, I have experienced high quality tipis with a special oven as extremely comfy, even when I did observations in snow covered mountains.

Presently, I have an Appartment which is near the university and near the forest, which are both good for my work. But in 11 months I will have to vacate it

However, our house has several shared toilets and I could always shower at the gym. Therefore the seemingly crazy question crosses my mind:

### Question

Would it be legal in Vienna, Austria to camp on the roof with my landlord‘s consent, provided I install sufficiently high lightning rods? Could we even formulate a contract?

Comment: Do you mean "camping on the roof now, as a hobby, to spend a night or two while I still have my appartment" or "camping on the roof after the lease of my appartment has expired, using the tent as my new home"?

Comment: @SJuan76 the second. But should not matter for the legal aspect. I have plenty of relatives here, where I can go in a storm, when the Tipi is not safe.

Comment: I also have a large basement in the same building. So all my library and desk can go there. But I know I need light ;)

Comment: Are the relatives in the same building you'd be camping on, i.e. so bathroom would be in the same building?  Could you officially domicile with the relatives but unofficially use the tipi most nights?  Is the roof actually built to be a recreational space intended for daily use by humans? (i.e. not merely repairman access)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica yes to everything except last point. In addition to the individual toilets in the appartments we have several that everyone can use (because after the war these were the only ones). No idea how it looks up there. Might also use one of the adjacent roofs. The point is: WOULD IT BE LEGAL?

Comment: I cant answer because I dont know Austrian law in this area so cant add an authoritative, but this would not be legal for the landlord to allow in the UK - there are restrictions on what a landlord can provide as a "permanent dwelling", and a tent on a roof would not meet those criteria.  Hence my doubt that this would be allowable.

Comment: @Moo landlord wouldn’t „provide it as a dwelling“ but would rent it. I would put my tent there. Would it be illegal?

Comment: @Ludi they are still providing it as a permanent dwelling, regardless of how you dress it up.

Comment: @Moo I don’t think that is correct. Suppose he rents me the garden and I put a tent there. Certainly, I am allowed to do so in my own garden.

Comment: @Ludi its the act of renting which changes the dynamic here.  You can do a lot in your own home that a landlord wouldnt be allowed to do or allow to happen for a tenant.

Comment: @Moo That should be easy to check, whether I can set up a tent in a garden that I have rented...

Comment: To get an accurate answer, you'll have to ask if you can set up a tent in a garden that you've rented _and regularly sleep there_.